# SPARQL query returning much more rows than expected

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm using the following SPARQL query to get a list of all US presidents together with the start and end dates of their presidency:

```
SELECT ?person $personLabel $start $end
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P39 wd:Q11696.
  ?person p:P39 ?statement.
  ?position_held_statement ps:P39 wd:Q11696.
  ?statement pq:P580 ?start. 
  ?statement pq:P582 ?end
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC($start)
```

[You can try it out here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%24personLabel%20%24start%20%24end%0A%23%3Fdate%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ11696.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20p%3AP39%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%3Fposition_held_statement%20ps%3AP39%20wd%3AQ11696.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP580%20%3Fstart.%20%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fend%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%24start%29%0A)

Why does it return so many rows?

**EDIT:** I know I can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get only distinct results, but I want to learn how I can find out the reason for the duplicates. Moreover, there are entries which state that Barack Obama's presidency lasted from January 2009 to January 2017, while others state his two terms separately.

Comment: you should also add another triple pattern `?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.`, otherwise you'll get 3 fictional characters like *Lex Luthor* (Superman/DC Universe) in the resultset. Or alternatively, exclude *fictional humans* via `filter not exists {?person wdt:P31 wd:Q15632617}`. And for completeness, the current president has no end date, so I'd do `optional {?statement pq:P582 ?end}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `?position_held_statement` there. That should be `?statement`.

When you unexpectedly have a lot of results in SPARQL, it’s usually because of mismatched variable names turning what should be a join into a cartesian product.